# Minimum amount of chars excluding space

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex like this (which is thanks to you guys in a big way):

```
(?<=( |\\s|\\A|^))@(!)[\\w]{3,}+ ?[\\w]*
```

Which works great however I now need to match one more case and I can't work out how to do it.  I need to have a minimum of 3 chars after the @ which I've done but I also need toallow for a minimum of 3 chars, at least two before a space and one after however a space is optional.  So I need to match these patterns:

```
@tst
@tst test
@ts t
```

How can I enforce a minimum of three chars if there's no space or a minimum of two chars, a space and then at least one more char?  I can do it as two seperate expressions but I'm hoping it's possible to do it with one?

Can anyone point me in the right direction..

Thanks.

EDIT:
Ok I think I've kind of achieved what I want with:

```
(?<=( |\\s|\\A|^))@{1}(([\\w]{3,}+ ?[\\w]*)|([\\w]{2,} {1}[\\w]{1,}))
```

Is there a more efficient way or is this how it should be done?

Comment: Ya.. that will pretty much do it..

Comment: Note that the space is redundant in the first part since you also have `\\s`.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure your regex behaves as you expect... See https://www.debuggex.com/r/fwHFxx61R2U1ImbQ. Could you give me the like to your first question (which made you have your first regex)?

Comment: It wasn't a specific question, just a couple of pointers on a few things I didn't understand (like how to use lookaround etc).  But you were right that regex didn't behave like I expected, I've updated my final regex above.

Comment: @crazyfool Play with https://www.debuggex.com/, it's a really great tool to understand regexps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplify your expression a bit:

```
String regex = "(?<=(\\s|\\A|^))@(\\w{2,} ?\\w+)";
```

What I have done:

- Removed the redundant space from the first part.
- Simplified the last expression. It now accepts, as per your description, a minimum of 2 characters, followed by an optional whitespace, followed by at least one more character.

I'm not sure what the point of the `(!)` part was, so it is removed in this version to match your test cases.

Comment: The problem with that solution (I think) is that it will allow any whitespace character between the strings when I only want to allow 1 space.  And also it will match @ab which I don't want to allow, it needs to be "@abc" or "@ab c"

Comment: This will not match `@ab`. It accepts 3 letters or more, with an optional whitespace somewhere after the second character. I have switched to whitespace instead of `\\s`.

Comment: My bad, just tried this again and looks like it does exactly what I want.  I'll test for a bit and then accept, thanks buddy :)

Comment: Just one more quick question which is a case I didn't think of before.. Is there an easy way to change the regex to also match "@abc " (note the space).. Or is that a whole other question

Comment: Actually ignore that.. Was a bug in my code, not your regex

Answer (score 1):

The following one should suit your needs:

```
(?<=(?<!\w)@)\w{2,} ?\w+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/iJlZgVZRPM2g0E6W)

Don't forget to escape the backslashes in Java since in a string literal:

```
(?<=(?<!\\w)@)\\w{2,} ?\\w+
```

Comment: Spoke too soon.. There's one pattern this misses out which is "@abc d"

Comment: @crazyfool Well, this input string does not respect the rule you gave: *"How can I enforce a minimum of three chars if there's no space or a minimum of two chars, a space and then at least one more char?"*. This input has 3 chars, then a space, then a char...

Comment: @sp00m: You are missing the _minimum_ part before the space. Read your quote again, 3 letters (or more) is perfectly fine too.

Comment: @Keppil You're right, I edited (i.e. added a comma ^^). Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest regex I can think of is:

```
(?<=\s|^)@(\s*\w){3,}
```